# How to display App loading in React native CLI (without expo)

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I added custom font in my CLI app by configuring it in react-native.config.js
Now i want to display Apploading splash screen till my font and other required assets loaded on screen and app is ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

### Adding Fonts

If you are using `react-native-cli` you dont need to use `AppLoading` component to add your fonts, you just have to follow these simple steps for React Native Version > **0.60**:

**STEP 1:** Add Fonts to Assets

Add the fonts you want to use to your project in `src/assets/fonts` for example.

**STEP 2:** Define assets directory (Which you already did i guess)

Create file **react-native.config.js** in your **root** project directory and add following code

```js
    module.exports = {
      assets: ["./src/assets/fonts/"],
    };
```

**STEP 3:** Link assets using react-native link

Run in terminal in your root project directory

```
$ npx react-native link
```

**NOTE:**

link command will link fonts in `Info.plst` for **IOS**, and creates fonts directory `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` for **Android**, where copies of your custom fonts will be stored.

### Splash screen

You can simply achieve that by configuring your **root navigator** e.g. `StackNavigator` to show a normal screen component that returns some sort of a loading indicator as the first screen to be rendered when your app first starts.

Then in that component, use `useEffect` to do some background tasks that need to be done before your app starts.

Finally, when the awaited tasks are done, simply navigate to your main app flow e.g. `HomeScreen.js` using the `navigation.navigate()` method.